# How to query a django model by shared values

Tags: python, django

I have a django model for user accounts, with a foreign key for user and a choice field for account type. It looks a bit like this:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    account_type = ChoiceField(models.TextField(
        choices=zip(ACCOUNT_TYPES, ACCOUNT_TYPES)
    )
```

I now want to add uniqueness to the model so each user can only have one account of each type, so I have added a unique_together in the meta with user and account type.

Unfortunately this model is quite old and already has a huge table, so I need to find duplicated objects (duplicated in that there is more than one object with the same user-account_type combo) so i can do something with them.

My question is - how can i query the `Account` table to find all the duplicated instances? I want something like

"Give me all objects where the user and account type is the same as the user and account type of any other object."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `annotate` and `Count`, something along the lines of:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Max

Account.objects.values('user', 'account_type')
    .order_by()
    .annotate(max_id=Max('id'), count_id=Count('id'))
    .filter(count_id__gt=1)
```

I am afraid I am not able to test this right now.

Comment: Yep this is what I was after, thank you, the max(id) was not needed by me but may be helpful to others